# windows not allowing me to replace file

Tags: python, delete-row, overwrite, file-rename

I'm using python to iterate through a csv file, and then delete a number of rows. To do this, I'm creating a new file and then attempting to remove the old file before then renaming the new file to the old file name. I keep getting an error and it's unclear to me as to why. The error is as follows:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "sendemails.py", line 85, in <module>
        os.remove('C:\Python27\emails.csv')
    WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Python27\\emails.csv'
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
FIRST_ROW_NUM = 1
ROWS_TO_DELETE = {1,3}

with open('C:\\Python27\\emails.csv', 'rt') as infile, open('C:\\Python27\\emailed.csv', 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(row for row_num, row in enumerate(infile, FIRST_ROW_NUM)
                        if row_num not in ROWS_TO_DELETE)

os.remove('C:\\Python27\\emails.csv')
os.rename('C:\\Python27\\emailed.csv','C:\\Python27\\emails.csv')
```

The csv file is not open anywhere that I'm aware of, and I printed the infile and outfile (to see whether closed) and both are closed prior to removing or renaming. Any help? I'm completely lost.

Comment: I see that your filenames are different.  In the with statement you access files named emails.csv and emailed.csv, but in the calls to `remove` they are full pathnames.  They might be the same files (depending on the current directory) and they might not.  The file named `C:\Python27\emails.csv` might very well be open in another process.

Comment: Also, you need to use double-backslashes, or raw strings.

Comment: I changed the filepaths as you mentioned to clear up some confusion. I had tried this before but the same error occurs. I also added the double backslash just in case. Same problem. Also to reiterate, neither file is open in any other visible way (eg; Notepad, Excel, etc.)

Comment: Okay, Windows must be accessing the file in some way or another because the script runs perfectly from a webserver. The script now works fine for my purposes, just not from Windows. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in some Microsoft Windows systems, if you open the file with another program, say the Notepad, the file cannot be deleted because it is being used by that program.